# SQL Nested Query using 3 tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have three tables Member, Branch, Mem_Branch. And i want to nest those tables. In mem_branch branchid and memberid is (foreignkey) and Branchname alongwith branchid is in Branch table and Memberid is in Member Table. Now i have a example suppose in mem_branch i have a memberid number 2 and his branchid is 1 and i want to display the branchname from Branch table whose branchid is 1 which relates to that memberid 2. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Branch.Branchname
FROM Branch
JOIN mem_branch ON mem_branch.branchid=Branch.branchid
WHERE mem_branch.memberid = 2 --AND mem_branch.branchid = 1
```

In last line uncomment `AND mem_branch.branchid = 1` if you really want to know name of only Branch with the id = 1 (what is a little bit strange, you may use direct select from table Branch without any connection to Members)